# How to display recent timestamp records and ignore the previous received timestamp records in SQL(databricks)

Tags: sql, hiveql, databricks-sql

select * from XYZ, the below shows the result set.

```
timestamp       |    Name
20221006050109  |    A 
20221006050109  |    B
20221006050109  |    C
20221006050109  |    D
20221007050125  |    E
20221007050125  |    F
20221007050125  |    G
20221007050125  |    H
```

My output should ignore the old timestamp and give me the records with latest timestamp

```
timestamp        |   Name    
20221007050125   |   E
20221007050125   |   F
20221007050125   |   G
20221007050125   |   H
```

i am doing this in Databricks on Hive table. i do not want to do with max(timestmap) since max is aggregation function and i explicitly want to ignore the data with old timestamp first then pick the data with latest timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RANK` function as approach here:

```
WITH ranked AS (
    SELECT timestamp, name,  RANK() OVER (ORDER BY timestamp DESC) rnk
    FROM tbl
) SELECT * FROM ranked WHERE rnk = 1;
```

[sql editor online](https://sqlize.online/sql/oracle19/f89fe79599648068c2e7e687098f22b4/)

Comment: Yes this is working, but i need to pass this output to view. which i am not able to do